# Create a dotted Dash effect outline in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have drawn a circle with Style.Stroke and a dasheffect supplied to the paint object but the issue is that the shape of the dashes are squared/rectangled.

What i wish to achieve is the dashed shapes to be circles/dots.

Is this possible?

I tried playing with the dash values but it simply tweaks the size and gaps of each dash instead of the shape of it.

Here is what i have written so far:

```
paintCircleDotted = new Paint();
        paintCircleDotted.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paintCircleDotted.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[] { 10, 5 }, (float) 1.0);
        paintCircleDotted.setPathEffect(dashPath);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use:

```
Paint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND)
```

Answer (score 6):

Hope someone find this helpful.

> To get actually round dots, you can define a circle.

```
Path path = new Path();
path.addCircle(0, 0, 6 /* Radius */, Path.Direction.CW);
```

> And use the path with the circle as our path effect

```
mArcPaint.setPathEffect(new PathDashPathEffect(path, 40 /* spacing between each stamp of shape */, 0, PathDashPathEffect.Style.ROTATE));
```